# How do I replace multiple characters with the same number of characters with a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've got the following source:

```
<font color="black">0</font><font color="white">1101100001001101</font><font color="black">1</font><font color="white">0110</font>
```

And would like to replace all *white* `1` and `0` with spaces. I can match them easily with

```
/<font color="white">([10]*)</font>/g
```

Is there a replace pattern (I'm using PHP) to generate the same number of spaces for the matching group `$1`?

The result should look like this:

```
<font color="black">0</font><font color="white">                </font><font color="black">1</font><font color="white">    </font>
```

(And please ignore the fact that [I'm parsing HTML with regexs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) here. I'm more interested in the solution to the regex problem than in the HTML.)

Comment: do u want this : http://ideone.com/5mn9g

Comment: No, I only want to replace the white 1/0s. The black 1/0 shall remain untouched.

Comment: Related/dupe for pure regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337995/regex-replace-sequence-of-one-character-with-same-number-of-another-character

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$test = '<font color="black">0</font><font color="white">1101100001001101</font><font color="black">1</font><font color="white">0110</font>';

echo preg_replace ('~(<font color="white">)([10]*)(</font>)~e', '"\\1" . str_repeat(" ", strlen ("\\2")) . "\\3"', $test);
```

Comment: That works fine. I just wondered if there's a regex-only way to do this, without resorting to PHP (`str_repeat`...).

Comment: @stema Ta. Actually, I like that you utilized assertions in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this here

```
<?php
$string = '<font color="black">0</font><font color="white">1101100001001101</font><font color="black">1</font><font color="white">0110</font>';
$pattern = '/(?<=<font color="white">)( *?)[10](?=.*?<\/font>)/';
$replacement = '$1 ';
while (preg_match($pattern, $string)) {
        $string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
}
echo $string;
```

I use a positive look behind `(?<=<font color="white">)` to search for the color part. And a positive look ahead `(?=.*?<\/font>)` for the end.

Then I match the already replaced spaces and put them into group 1 and then the `[10]`.

Then I do a while loop until the pattern do not match anymore and a replace with the already replaces spaces and the new found space.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will only match `1` | `0` if it's preceded with `"white">`.
the `(?<=...)` syntax in regex is called positive lookbehind...

```
(?<="white">)([10]+)
```

Comment: This will also replace the pipe char `|`, there's no need of it inside a class.

Comment: Hmm, that matches fine too, but the replacement by the same number of characters is the problem.