# Replace regex with same number of chars

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace the content found used a regex with the same number of characters using a character defined by me.

For example:

```
content: "abcdefghi*!?\"asd";
```

should becomes:

```
content: "-----------------";
```

This is my regexp:

```
new RegExp("('|\").*('|\")", "gm")
```

And this is my attempt took from this answer ([Javascript Regex- replace sequence of characters with same number of another character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456559/javascript-regex-replace-sequence-of-characters-with-same-number-of-another-cha)):

```
source_text_safe = source_text.replace(new RegExp("('|\").*('|\")", "gm"), function ($0, $1, $2, $3) {
            return $1 + (new Array($2.length + 1).join("-")) + $3;
        });
```

But it doesn't work.

Using it on this input:

```
::selected {
    color: purple
}
a {
    color: purple
}
a:hover {
    color: purple
}
a {
    color: purple
}
a:not("foobar\";{}omg") {
    content: 'example\';{} text';
    content: "example\";}{ text"
}
a {
    color: purple
}
```

I get this output:

```
::selected {
    color: purple
}
a {
    color: purple
}
a:hover {
    color: purple
}
a {
    color: purple
}
a:not("-117) {
    content: '-150;
    content: "-184
}
a {
    color: purple
}
```

If I use the regexp replacing the content with **`null`** it works fine, so is not a problem of regex.

Any help?

Comment: Related/dupe for pure regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337995/regex-replace-sequence-of-one-character-with-same-number-of-another-character

Answer (score 0):

The replacement function requires three (catching) groups to be present in the regular expression but there are only two of them. Therefore the `$3` gets the offset of the match which is the unexpected number you get. For details see [Specifying a funciton as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) in Mozilla JS reference.

Use something like `"('|\")(.*)('|\")"` (3 groups) for your regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Ok seems I've solved it...

```
source_text_safe = source_text.replace(new RegExp("('|\").*('|\")", "gm"), function ($0) {
    return (new Array($0.length + 1).join("-"));
});
```

Thanks for all the answers however.