# Javascript Regex- replace sequence of characters with same number of another character

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to replace part of a string with the same number of dummy characters in JavaScript, for example: '==Hello==' with '==~~~~~=='.

This question has been answered using [Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337995/regex-replace-sequence-of-one-character-with-same-number-of-another-character) and [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149555/how-do-i-replace-multiple-characters-with-the-same-number-of-characters-with-a-re), but I can't get it to work in JavaScript. I've been trying this:

```
txt=txt.replace(/(==)([^=]+)(==)/g, "$1"+Array("$2".length + 1).join('~')+"$3");
```

The pattern match works fine, but the replacement does not - the second part adds '~~' instead of the length of the pattern match. Putting the "$2" inside the parentheses doesn't work. What can I do to make it insert the right number of characters?

Comment: Related/dupe for pure regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337995/regex-replace-sequence-of-one-character-with-same-number-of-another-character

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a function for replacement instead:

```
var txt = "==Hello==";
txt = txt.replace(/(==)([^=]+)(==)/g, function ($0, $1, $2, $3) {
    return $1 + (new Array($2.length + 1).join("~")) + $3;
});

alert(txt);
//-> "==~~~~~=="
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue with the expression

```
txt.replace(/(==)([^=]+)(==)/g, "$1"+Array("$2".length + 1).join('~')+"$3")
```

is that `"$2".length` forces `$2` to be taken as a string literal, namely the string `"$2"`, that has length 2.

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Using_an_inline_function_that_modifies_the_matched_characters):

> Because we want to further transform the *result* of the match before the final substitution is made, we must use a function.

This forces evaluation of the match before the transformation.

With an inline function as parameter (and `repeat`) -- here `$1, $2, $3` are local variables:

```
txt.replace(/(==)([^=]+)(==)/g, (_,$1,$2,$3) => $1+'~'.repeat($2.length)+$3);
```

```js
txt = '==Hello==';

//inline function
console.log(
  txt.replace(/(==)([^=]+)(==)/g, (_, g1, g2, g3) => g1 + '~'.repeat(g2.length) + g3)
);
```

Comment: Very neat answer, and it works in my case also.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The length attribute is being evaluated before the $2 substitution so replace() won't work.  The function call suggested by Augustus should work, another approach would be using match() instead of replace().

Using match() without the /g, returns an array of match results which can be joined as you expect.

```
txt="==Hello==";
mat=txt.match(/(==)([^=]+)(==)/);  // mat is now ["==Hello==","==","Hello","=="]
txt=mat[1]+Array(mat[2].length+1).join("~")+mat[3]; // txt is now "==~~~~~=="
```

You excluded the leading/trailing character from the middle expression, but if you want more flexibility you could use this and handle anything bracketed by the leading/trailing literals.

```
mat=txt.match(/(^==)(.+)(==$)/)
```

Answer (score 0):

A [working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/YKm9h/1/) uses the following fragment:

```
var processed = original.replace(/(==)([^=]+)(==)/g, function(all, before, gone, after){
    return before+Array(gone.length+1).join('~')+after;
});
```

The problem in your code was that you always measured the length of `"$2"` (always a string with two characters). By having the function you can measure the length of the matched part. See the [documentation on replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for further examples.

Comment: Your code has a slight error in it and will return one character less than expected. This is because the array length needs to be 1 more than the string length for `join()` to produce a replacement string of equal length.